# Is wstring::npos equal to -1 in cpp definitions?

Tags: c++

```
int FDString::
ReverseFind(const FDString& searchString, int rend) const
 { 
return static_cast(mString.rfind(searchString.mString), rend == nPos ? String::npos : rend);
 }
```

Here i have defined

```
ifdef UNICODE
#define String std::wstring
#else
#define String std::string
#endif
```

I am sure std::string::npos is defined in cpp reference as -1 but in wstring i am not sure if its explicitly defined as -1? so can i assume std::wstring::npos is also -1?

Comment: Why do you need to? However remember that `std::string` and `std::wstring` are `typedefs` of a `template` class `std::basic_string`. So `npos` is the same for both. Also you could use `typedef` or `using` rather than `#macros'.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.

`wstring` is a `typedef` to `basic_string`

```
typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;
```

On the other hand, `string` is also `typedef` to `basic_string`

```
typedef basic_string<char> string;
```

`nops` is defined in `basic_string`, so is should be same in both types.

and it is defined as,

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

refer

- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/npos/

Answer (score 1):

*npos* is defined in `std::basic_string` which is the base class of `std::string` and `std::wstring`.
So it is the same in both classes.